# Having a problem with ID`s in my Minecraft Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I want to create a randomizer plugin. I need the IDs for my shuffeled ArrayList. The problem is that for whatever reason i just can`t get the ID of the Block.

Error message:

> Could not pass event BlockBreakEvent to MyPlugin
> org.bukkit.event.EventException: null at
> org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:319)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:70)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:589)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:576)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerInteractManager.breakBlock(PlayerInteractManager.java:309)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerInteractManager.a(PlayerInteractManager.java:268)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerInteractManager.a(PlayerInteractManager.java:213)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1219)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PacketPlayInBlockDig.a(SourceFile:40)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PacketPlayInBlockDig.a(SourceFile:10)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:19)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(SourceFile:144)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(SourceFile:118)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.ba(MinecraftServer.java:941)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:934)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(SourceFile:127)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:918)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:850)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271] Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get ID of Modern Material
> at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:136)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> org.bukkit.Material.getId(Material.java:3576)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] at
> en.me.myplugin.listeners.Listeners.onBlockBreakEvent(Listeners.java:100)
> ~[?:?] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor216.invoke(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?] at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_271] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_271] at
> org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:315)
> ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-379750e-43c7ff9] ... 21 more

Code:

```
event.getBlock().getWorld().dropItemNaturally(event.getBlock().getLocation(), new ItemStack(randomizer.randomize.get(event.getBlock().getType().getId())));
```

getId() is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

*I would Comment but since I can't:*

Just read the errors, they're pretty straight forward. Also you should perhaps post this on something like the spigot forum and not here. Also only because it's deprecated doesn't mean it won't work.

Also you should show us your randomizer.randomize class/array/list.

Comment: public static List<Material> randomize = new ArrayList<>();
 for (Player players : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
  for(Material material: Material.values()) {
   randomizer.randomize.add(material);   
      Collections.shuffle(randomizer.randomize);
  }
I tested it. It didnt work.

Comment: and what are the values of the `Material` HashMap / Dictionary?

Comment: It`s all the Materials of Minecraft (Their Names)

Comment: btw you're trying to use a Material as Integer (for the index)